# Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 8. Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having troubles in

> Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 8. Google Script

```
function myFunction() {
    var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Staging');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var Avals = s2.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++)
  {
    var keep = false;
    var counter = 0;
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++)
    {
      if( values1[n][1] == values2[p][1])
      {
        keep = true;
        break ;
      }
    }
    if(keep == false)
    {
      resultArray.push([values1[n]]);   
      //s2.appendRow( values1[n] );
      s2.getRange(Alast + 1, 1, values1[n].length, values1[n].length).setValues([values1[n]]);
      //s2.getRange(s2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values1.length, values1[0].length).appendRow( values1[n] );
      resultArray = [];
      keep = false
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to keep appending a new row to the end of the data on "Final".  You should revise you script as shown below.  Use `resultArray` to collect all new rows and save it to spreadsheet once.

```
function myFunction() {
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Staging');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  // s2.getDataRange() will get up to the last row of data
  var Alast = values2.length;

  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++)
  {
    var keep = false;
    var counter = 0;
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++)
    {
      if( values1[n][1] == values2[p][1])
      {
        keep = true;
        break ;
      }
    }
    if(keep == false)
    {
      resultArray.push(values1[n]);   
      keep = false
    }  
  }
  if( resultArray.length > 0 ) {
    s2.getRange(Alast+1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
  }
}
```